# Where is my php.ini file location defined?

Tags: configuration, php

```
[root@localhost \]# php -i | grep Configuration
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

Comment: Loaded Configuration File -> none, that is what is confusing me.

Comment: do you have  a file called php.ini in that folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use this instead

```
php --ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following php script:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

and run it throw browser. It will contain "Loaded Configuration File" with path to loaded php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

That is for CLI, 
Run `phpinfo()` and run it thought CGI (apache).

Also, in order to help you you need to post more information!

Comment: i need to run my scripts as cli

Answer (score -1):

it seems that apache has no right to read php.ini file under "/usr/local/lib" check the rights for